# Strange class precedence list in sbcl

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, clos, mop

In sbcl,

```
*(sb-mop:class-precedence-list (find-class 'cons))
==>(#<BUILT-IN-CLASS CONS> #<BUILT-IN-CLASS LIST> #<BUILT-IN-CLASS SEQUENCE>
 #<BUILT-IN-CLASS T>)
```

Isn't it strange that cons inherits from list and not the other way around? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is per the [specification](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_cons.htm). A [LIST](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_list.htm) is either a [CONS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_cons.htm), or a symbol NIL (which is the only object of type [NULL](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_null.htm)), which means that both of those types are specializations of LIST, and hence their equivalent system classes inherit from LIST.

Comment: I thought the definition of list included the requirement that the cdr of the last cell is nil...

Comment: That is the requirement for non-empty proper list. This is explained in the link for LIST.

Answer (score -1):

Not all conses are lists (since the ultimate cdr might not be nil), and not all lists are conses (nil is not a list, as mentioned earlier).  So technically speaking, neither is of a class that is properly a subclass of the other.  I think the spec is written that way because someone saw a practical use, but I agree that it's confusing and it might be misguided.

Comment: According to the accepted answer which is correct, all conses are lists. They just arent necessarily proper lists.